# Finding the coefficient of a certain power in a generating function

Tags: list-manipulation, polynomials, series-expansion, integer-sequence

I want to compute $(t^1+\dots +t^5)(t^2+\dots+ t^6)(t^3+\dots +t^9)$ and find the coefficient of $t^{15}$ for example. $t$ is an indeterminate

Now in *Maple* this is simply as

```
p:=sum(t^i,i=1..5)*sum(t^i,i=2..6)*sum(t^i,i=3..9);
coeff(p,t,15);
```

But I can't seem to learn how to do this in *Mathematica*.

I have tried using

```
Series[ %, {t, 1, 10}] * Series[ %, {t, 4, 20}] * Series[ %, {t, 6, 15}]
```

But it outputs a number(I don't know what this number even is)

Where can I find documentation to solve such a problem?

Comment: What exactly is `%`?

Comment: From here @Öskå http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeneratingFunction.html.

It seems they get what I want, but I exchange $x$ for $t$

Comment: @Öskå Oh that is embarrassing, `%` refers to previous entry

Comment: I know, so I was asking what was the previous output, but never mind, the answer is down there :)

Comment: To closevoters: Did you reallly read the question? Doesn't it really concern _Mathematica_?

Answer (score 12):

There is a straightforward answer analogous to that in *Maple* :

```
Coefficient[ Sum[t^i, {i, 5}] Sum[t^i, {i, 2, 6}] Sum[t^i, {i, 3, 9}], t, 15]
```

> ```
> 19
> ```

This can be verified by expanding the polynomial:

```
Expand[ Sum[t^i, {i, 5}] Sum[t^i, {i, 2, 6}] Sum[t^i, {i, 3, 9}]]
```

However you can do it in many different ways e.g. by exploiting `CoefficientRules` or `MonomialList` nevertheless the best way for the problem at hand is `Coefficient`.

It appears more useful when we deal with huge order polynomials and a variable  number of them. Then we would rather use also **different ways to generate** such polynomials, especially more convenient and universal ones.
Here are two alternative ways:

```
Times @@ (Sum[t^i, {i, ##}] & @@@ {{5}, {2, 6}, {3, 9}})
```

Instead of `Sum` one can exploit powerful *Mathematica*  capabilities to deal with lists ( see the `Listable` attribute) :

```
Times @@ (Total[t^Range[##]] & @@@ {{5}, {2, 6}, {3, 9}})
```

In both ways we can generate arbitrarily involved polynomial expressions of the given type.

**Edit**

It's rather surprising how `Coefficient` appears to be much faster if we expand given polynomial as observed by [mathe](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58850/finding-the-coefficient-of-a-certain-power-in-a-generating-function/58857#comment169261_58857).

Let's compare timings for a huge polynomial expression:

```
(*Coefficient without Expand*)
Coefficient[ Sum[t^i, {i, 500}] Sum[t^i, {i, 20, 600}] Sum[t^i, {i, 30, 900}],
              t, 1500] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {256.218000, 125750}
> ```

```
(*MichaelE2's approach *)

power = 1500;
(p1 = Series[Sum[t^i, {i, 500}], {t, 0, power}];
 p2 = Series[Sum[t^i, {i, 20, 600}], {t, 0, power}];
 p3 = Series[Sum[t^i, {i, 30, 900}], {t, 0, power}];
SeriesCoefficient[p1 p2 p3, power]) // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {1.272000, 125750}
> ```

```
(*Coefficient with Expand*)

Coefficient[ Sum[t^i, {i, 500}] Sum[t^i, {i, 20, 600}] Sum[t^i, {i, 30, 900}]
             // Expand, t, 1500] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.147000, 125750}
> ```

**Conclusion:** **`Expand` is crucial for higher degree polynomials**!

Comment: I see, very nice, thank you!

Comment: I recommend to wait for different answers before accepting one at least a few hours, then you will see how many ways to solve probelems there are in _Mathematica_.

Comment: Probably a good idea, since I will pick up syntax(like my original fail visible in OP comments)

Comment: @Algebra Since you've got quite nice answers to your question you should at least read them, then upvote if they are helpful or if they are misleading downvote and decide which one is the best accepting it.

Comment: Sorry, I do greatly appreciate these answers and will thoroughly read them over the weekend. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I can't discern the best answer, so I will give it more time, sorry!

Answer (score 11):

[@Artes's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/184/artes) use of `Coefficient` certainly seems the most straightforward and probably the best for small examples.  If the polynomials have very many terms, the use of [`SeriesData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SeriesData.html) to represent the polynomials will give better performance.  The multiplication of series is efficient in *Mathematica*.  One should note that it is truncated beyond the maximum degree represented, so we need to take care to specify it appropriately.

The format of `SeriesData` is given in the documentation:

```
SeriesData[x, x0, coeffs, nmin, nmax, den]
```

This represents a series in the variable `x` centered at `x0`.  The argument `coeffs` is a list of coefficients beginning with the least degree which is specified by `nmin`.  The argument `nmax` is the maximum power represented; if the list `coeffs` is shorter than `nmax - nmin + 1`, the missing coefficients are taken to be zero.  The argument `den` is the denominator of the powers, used to represent fractional powers; we will only use `den = 1`.  [`SeriesCoefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SeriesCoefficient.html) will extract a coefficient.

Here is one way to apply this idea to the OP's example:

```
power = 15;
p1 = Series[Sum[t^i, {i, 5}], {t, 0, power}];
p2 = Series[Sum[t^i, {i, 2, 6}], {t, 0, power}] ;
p3 = Series[Sum[t^i, {i, 3, 9}], {t, 0, power}];
SeriesCoefficient[p1 p2 p3, power]
(* 
  19
*)
```

**Speed**

The difference in speed comes mainly from the efficiency of multiplying the series compared to the differentiation/multiplication of the polynomial (or however `Coefficient` works).

```
power = 1500;
(p1 = Series[Sum[t^i, {i, 500}], {t, 0, power}];
  p2 = Series[Sum[t^i, {i, 20, 600}], {t, 0, power}] ;
  p3 = Series[Sum[t^i, {i, 30, 900}], {t, 0, power}];
 SeriesCoefficient[p1 p2 p3, power]) // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {0.610942, 125750}
*)

Coefficient[Sum[t^i, {i, 500}] Sum[t^i, {i, 20, 600}] Sum[t^i, {i, 30, 900}], t, 1500] //
  AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {151.011174, 125750}
*)
```

The interesting thing about the multiplication of series is that it seems to be cached by the system.  So if you want several coefficients, the multiplication is not recomputed.  Subsequent calls are much faster:

```
SeriesCoefficient[p1 p2 p3, power] // AbsoluteTiming
SeriesCoefficient[p1 p2 p3, 500] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {0.000034, 125750}
  {0.000013, 101475}
*)
```

Of course one could have saved the product in variable, `prod = p1 p2 p3`.  But I thought it was worth noting.

Remark: If the lowest degree in one or more polynomials is high, then more time can be saved by reducing the maximum power of the other series.  For example, we can save a tenth of a second:

```
power = 1500;
mind1 = 1; mind2 = 20; mind3 = 30;
(p1 = SeriesData[t, 0, Table[1, {i, 500}], 1, power - (mind2 + mind3) + 1, 1];
  p2 = SeriesData[t, 0, Table[1, {i, 20, 600}], 20, power - (mind1 + mind3) + 1, 1] ;
  p3 = SeriesData[t, 0, Table[1, {i, 30, 900}], 30, power - (mind1 + mind2) + 1, 1];
  SeriesCoefficient[p1 p2 p3, power]) // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {0.498997, 125750}
*)
```

Remark 2: I just noticed I snuck in the direct generation of coefficients, basically replacing `Sum` by `Table`, without comment.  That also speeds up the computation, but only a little.  I might also add that if other coefficients are desired, `power` in the last line may be replaced by any integer less than or equal to `power`.

Comment: Nice performance +1!

Comment: Try `Coefficient[Sum[t^i,{i,500}] Sum[t^i,{i,20,600}] Sum[t^i,{i,30,900}]//Expand,t,1500]//AbsoluteTiming`.

Comment: @mathe Wow, what a surprising difference! (I get 0.013 sec by way of comparison.) I don't know if that's worth a separate answer.  It's a simple adjustment but a major improvement you've discovered.