# Extracting coefficients from a power series

Tags: function-construction, series-expansion

I have a function defined explicitly as a power series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{T_n}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{\frac{x^3}{3!}}{e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2!}}$$ 
and I would like to extract the coefficients $T_k$ as $k$ runs over the whole numbers.  I know there is a coefficient function and a table function which I think would probably be the easiest.  Taking this one step further, can I extract just the denominator of each coefficient?

If I define $t[n]=\frac{\frac{x^3}{3!}}{e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2!}}$, should I just use seriescoefficient and set my bounds as say run it over $n=0..25$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's something which returns the denominators. Is this what you are looking for?

```
Denominator[(#! SeriesCoefficient[(x^3/6)/(
      E^x - 1 - x - x^2/2), {x, 0, #}] & /@ Range[0, 25])]
```

which returns

```
{1, 4, 40, 160, 5600, 896, 19200, 76800, 14784000, 19712000, \
512512000, 186368000, 19568640000, 6021120000, 20889600000, \
7798784000, 71310131200000, 16778854400000, 503365632000000, \
15138816000000, 221798793216000000, 6035341312000000, \
38406717440000000, 6679429120000000, 3857370316800000000, \
24687170027520000}
```

Comment: yes, my only issue is I'm looking explicitly for the coefficients $T_k$.  The denominators here include the factorial term inherent in the power series.  For example, $T_2=\frac{1}{40}$, but the sequence above has $\frac{1}{40}\frac{1}{2!}$...

Comment: @ybeltukov: D'oh!

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: Fixed it (I think?).

Comment: That looks more like it to me...Thank you for the help!

Comment: The `#!` is really jarring to those of us used to the unix shell.

Answer (score 4):

Use SeriesCoefficient.

Let

```
g[x_] := x^3/3!/(Exp[x] - 1 - 1 - x^2/2!)
```

Then calculate the power series up to power m

```
s[m_] := Series[g[x], {x, 0, m}]
```

Finally, your coefficients are

```
t[n_]:=SeriesCoefficient[s[n], n] n!
```

Example

```
Table[t[n], {n, 0, 10}]

(* {0, 0, 0, -1, -4, -20, -140, -1155, -10696, -111132, -1285320} *)
```

Regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: I noticed the numbers are not right.  I'm thinking it is due to your definition of the function:  in the denominator you have Exp{x}-1-1-x^2/2! instead of Exp{x}-1-x-x^2/2!.  That would probably fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Since [`SeriesData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SeriesData.html) is a documented data structure, it seems suitable to take advantage of it.  We can calculate the series just once, which in this case will be more than 40 times faster than DumpsterDoofus's method and 12 times faster than Dr. Wolgang Hintze's.  (It's tricky to time, since `Series`/`SeriesData` cache their results to make subsequent calls a bit faster. [I had forgotten that.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58850/finding-the-coefficient-of-a-certain-power-in-a-generating-function/58857#58857) In this comparison each timing was made with a fresh kernel. If the maximum power goes up to `100`, the ratios of the times decreases to 12 and 2.5 times, respective, although the absolute time difference increases.)

```
With[{s = Series[(x^3/6)/(E^x - 1 - x - x^2/2), {x, 0, 25}]},
 PadRight[s[[3]], -s[[4]] + s[[5]]] Range[s[[4]], s[[5]] - 1]! // Denominator
 ]
(* {1, 4, 40, 160, ..., 24687170027520000} *)
```

`SeriesData` has the structure

```
SeriesData[x, x0, coefficients, min, max, den]
```

where `x` is the variable, `x0` is the center, `min` and `max` are the limits on the powers, and `den` is the denominator in fractional power series.  The code above assumes the usual sort of power series with `den == 1`.  The coefficients are obtained with `s[[3]]`.  The range of powers is `s[[4]]` to `s[[5]]`.  One thing to beware is that the coefficients are trimmed of zeros at the ends.  This is the reason for the padding and the arguments to `Range`.  To always get the coefficients from the power `0` to the maximum power, one could use

```
PadRight[ArrayPad[s[[3]], {s[[4]], 0}], s[[5]]] Range[0, s[[5]] - 1]!
```

Comment: (at) Michael E2: interesting function SeriesData, but the exection time is not an argument. I have chosen delayed assignment in s[m_]:=... because m is unknown. If we know it in advance (as you do in your example with m = 25) we let s[m_] = ... and even for m = 320 the table of values (without displaying it) is calculated very quickly in 0.016 secs.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Yes, I did the timing wrong.  One has to start each trial from a fresh kernel.  I forgot that the `SeriesData` is cached.  For `m = 100`, I get about `0.4` sec. for your code and `0.15` sec. for mine.  For `m = 320`, I got tired of waiting.

Comment: (at) Michael E2: for the sake of completeness, I repeated the run with a fresh kernel. The result is the same (0.016 secs), Version 8.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze In V10, your `Table[t[n], {n, 0, 320}]; //AbsoluteTiming` took 37.9 sec.  In V8, it took 75.5 sec.  That's quite a difference from your timings.  (I'm on a 2.7GHz quad-core i7 Mac.  I included the code in case we're trying different things.)

Comment: @ Michael E2: you are right, my numbers were wrong. I wrote 1 instead of x in g[]. But after correcting it the execution time remained the same. BTW it needs 4.368 secs to calculate s[m] with m=320. My code see next comment.

Comment: @ Michael E2: With a fresh kernel run this code and compare g[x_] := x^3/3!/(Exp[x] - 1 - x - x^2/2!)
Timing[s[m_] = Series[g[x], {x, 0, 320}];]
t[n_] := SeriesCoefficient[s[n], n] n!
Timing[tW=Table[t[n], {n, 0, 320}];]
tM = Table[t[n], {n, 0, 320}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 4.477, 0, 0.0040003 *) I get similar results for V8 and for V5.2. My Windows-PC is nothing special at all.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze It takes 9.5 sec to evaluate the definition of `s[m_]` in your last comment plus 0.0029 sec to evaluate the table `tW`. Mine takes only 3.45 sec this morning (I'm sure it was taking much longer yesterday), but I repeated it.  The time to compute `s[m_]` is significant and must be included in the total, as that is where the principal computation occurs.  So yours is about 2.8 times slower....cont'd

Comment: ... Your new code for `s` does not match the definition in your answer; the new code takes advantage of the cacheing of `Series` results by computing the `Series` only once for m = 320, which is more or less what my answer does.  I'm not sure what the reason for the big difference in timing. The old code in your answer recomputes the series for m = 0, 1,..., 320, if we go up to 320.  That is a much slower approach.

Comment: Yes, I think we agree now ... and your Mac is faster :-)

Comment: Yes, I think we do, but I don't know what's happening with the timing. I can now sometimes get my code to take 9.5 sec and sometimes I can get yours from the comment to take 3.5.  I think they should be roughly the same, the major computation being the series, which is the same in both. Accessing the coefficients one at a time in your `Table` is less efficient than the vectorized approach in my answer, but the order of magnitude is 10^-5 sec per access, which is negligible compared to 3-10 sec. Not worth figuring out, really.  Have a good day. :)

Comment: It is common to observe rather apreciable "stochastic" fluctuations in execution times under nominally equal conditions. There's a whole lot of processes running on the machine which make it virtually impossible to guarantee equal conditions. Maybe it's that effect?