# Trouble with polynomial multiplication

Tags: bugs, evaluation, polynomials

**Bug introduced in 10.1.0 and fixed in 10.4.0**

---

```
Coefficient[
Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000}] 
Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 2}]
Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 5}]
Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 10}]
Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 20}]
Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 50}]
Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 100}] // Expand, x, 1000] // AbsoluteTiming

{0.032555, 11583833929}
```

That is why I love Mathematica. Now I just tack on another polynomial...

```
Coefficient[
Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000}] 
Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 2}]
Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 5}]
Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 10}]
Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 20}]
Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 50}]
Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 100}]
Sum[x^k,{k,0,1000,200}] // Expand, x, 1000] // AbsoluteTiming

{0.039276, -190969169941}
```

How do I get a negative coefficient for x^1000 when all those polys have positive coefficients? Where did I go wrong?

I am afraid that in light of Bob's calculations which I know are correct I am going to have to say that this is a bug in 10.1 when running on Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca.

If I do it this way:

```
Coefficient[
Series[Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000}], {x, 0, 1000}]
Series[Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 2}], {x, 0, 1000}]
Series[Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 5}], {x, 0, 1000}]
Series[Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 10}], {x, 0, 1000}]
Series[Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 20}], {x, 0, 1000}]
Series[Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 50}], {x, 0, 1000}]
Series[Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 100}], {x, 0, 1000}], x, 1000] // AbsoluteTiming

{0.009989, 234896541}

Coefficient[
Series[Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000}], {x, 0, 1000}]
Series[Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 2}], {x, 0, 1000}]
Series[Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 5}], {x, 0, 1000}]
Series[Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 10}], {x, 0, 1000}]
Series[Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 20}], {x, 0, 1000}]
Series[Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 50}], {x, 0, 1000}]
Series[Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 100}], {x, 0, 1000}]
Series[Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 1000, 200}], {x, 0, 1000}] , x, 1000] // AbsoluteTiming


{0.007549, 321335886}
```

we get the correct answer, this is probably due to fact that the series command truncates each poly not allowing intermediate calculations to trigger the anomaly that happens when large polys are multiplied in 10.1 on this OS.

Comment: With v10.1 on a Mac, I do not get the same results as you did. I get `234896541` for the first coefficient and `321335886` for the second. By the way, the use of `Expand` is not necessary to get the coefficients.

Comment: @Bob I am using 10.1 on Linux Mint, I can show a screenshot.

Comment: Try starting with a fresh kernel.

Comment: @Bob Hi, I did and I used expand because it is supposed to speed up the computation.

Comment: Yes it is much faster with the `Expand`, I recant my heresy.

Comment: @BobHanlon: See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58851/11467)...

Comment: That is where I got the speedup from.

Comment: Added the [tag:bugs] tag; thanks for not putting it yourself until others have tried things. :)

Comment: @Guess who it is I always assume it is me that is making the mistake and I have always been right.

Comment: I think your timings on `Series` are because `Series` caches its computations.  When you repeat them, it just looks up the previous result. (Correct answer aside).

Comment: @Michael E2 You are correct, I only provided the timings to encourage people to try the code knowing that it is not going to bog their machine down. It indicates that this is a trivial calculation for mathematica.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update**

This bug has been fixed in Mathematica [10.4.0](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn104.html).

---

I can confirm the above incorrect results are due to a bug in the Intel MKL library shipping with *Mathematica* 10.1 which affects FFT convolution. The problem is only known to be triggered on some processors (for example AMD chips, or virtual machine emulated CPUs).

The following workaround will use an alternative implementation that does not rely on MKL

```
SetSystemOptions["FourierOptions" -> {"ConvolutionLibrary" -> "Mathematica"}];
```

Comment: That is an important bit of info and fix for me, thank you.

Comment: Can you update the version where it got fixed?  The problem is not present with my CPU.

Comment: @Szabolcs Still present in 10.3 (it affects fairly "exotic" CPUs), but I expect it will be fixed in the next release.