# Speeding the calculation of a complex polynomial from its roots

Tags: performance-tuning, programming, polynomials

Suppose I have a list of (complex, in my case) numbers, and I want to construct the coefficients of the monic polynomial of which they are the roots. The obvious way:

```
poly[n_]:= CoefficientList[Expand[Product[x-list[[i]],{i, 1, n}]], x]
```

Seems to take quartic time in $n,$ and for $n=5000$ takes about a minute on my MacBook Pro.

The less obvious way:

```
poly2[n_]:= CoefficientList[CharacteristicPolynomial[DiagonalMatrix[list], x], x]
```

Is much faster (takes 8 seconds for the same computation) but it's hard to believe that this is optimal. Any ideas?

**Edit** There is also `InterpolatingPolynomial`, but that is *slower* than the `CharacteristicPolynomial` scheme.

**More interesting edit**
Upon meditating on this for a while, I came up with the following:

```
cfromr[roots_] := 
 With[{n = Length[roots], 
   f = Compile[{{x, _Complex}}, 
     Product[(x - roots[[i]]), {i, 1, Length[roots]}]]},
  Module[{fvals = Array[f[Exp[(# - 1) 2 Pi I/(n + 1)]] &, n + 1]},
   InverseFourier[fvals]/Sqrt[n + 1]]]
```

Let's try it:

```
cfromr[{1}]
{-1., 1.}

cfromr[{1, 1}]
{1., -2., 1.}

cfromr[{1, 2, 3}]
{-6., 11., -6., 1.}
```

Cool! And of course, it is fast as blazes (orders of magnitude faster than the previous efforts - try it). But, let's just try it for something a little more complicated, and compare it with the boneheaded approach below:

```
stupidCfromR[roots_] := 
 CoefficientList[Product[x - roots[[i]], {i, 1, Length[roots]}], x]
```

OK,

```
foo = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100]
{0.615659, 0.749481, 0.877498, 0.179083, 0.580726, 0.297616, 0.436366, \
0.885845, 0.207169, 0.979251, 0.768706, 0.962705, 0.934818, 0.558659, \
0.810448, 0.578337, 0.880773, 0.0389867, 0.561441, 0.636913, \
0.747634, 0.061617, 0.686383, 0.149683, 0.413282, 0.659633, 0.534624, \
0.266132, 0.16876, 0.29776, 0.156488, 0.678895, 0.287585, 0.192998, \
0.527663, 0.352505, 0.718803, 0.380109, 0.44967, 0.46576, 0.693758, \
0.557772, 0.811107, 0.824323, 0.77316, 0.365756, 0.283581, 0.849779, \
0.0787828, 0.180125, 0.0536948, 0.406494, 0.570083, 0.458642, \
0.209918, 0.0254337, 0.340365, 0.280486, 0.0969694, 0.902567, \
0.311759, 0.445944, 0.734187, 0.556372, 0.968549, 0.722562, 0.885184, \
0.642906, 0.264817, 0.541621, 0.793586, 0.259047, 0.0489964, \
0.183852, 0.499949, 0.0692111, 0.714986, 0.793983, 0.525797, \
0.508116, 0.0739616, 0.0726041, 0.542157, 0.143221, 0.980601, \
0.994549, 0.542997, 0.77058, 0.706582, 0.858526, 0.00312537, \
0.0235296, 0.961969, 0.436431, 0.611778, 0.167991, 0.424293, \
0.0989057, 0.256478, 0.732805}

stupidCfromR[foo]
{6.56546*10^-45, -5.01907*10^-42, 1.56046*10^-39, -2.8729*10^-37, 
 3.64875*10^-35, -3.47096*10^-33, 2.60308*10^-31, -1.59376*10^-29, 
 8.17047*10^-28, -3.57511*10^-26, 1.35545*10^-24, -4.50701*10^-23, 
 1.32751*10^-21, -3.49263*10^-20, 8.2664*10^-19, -1.77082*10^-17, 
 3.4517*10^-16, -6.15044*10^-15, 1.00596*10^-13, -1.5158*10^-12, 
 2.11112*10^-11, -2.72564*10^-10, 3.27087*10^-9, -3.65718*10^-8, 
 3.81829*10^-7, -3.72996*10^-6, 0.0000341544, -0.00029365, \
0.00237425, -0.0180782, 0.129804, -0.879936, 5.63813, -34.1814, \
196.26, -1068.19, 5515.59, -27039.4, 125940., -557668., 
 2.34902*10^6, -9.41749*10^6, 3.5953*10^7, -1.30763*10^8, 
 4.53272*10^8, -1.49802*10^9, 4.72179*10^9, -1.41987*10^10, 
 4.07431*10^10, -1.11587*10^11, 2.91749*10^11, -7.28283*10^11, 
 1.73593*10^12, -3.9513*10^12, 8.58888*10^12, -1.78288*10^13, 
 3.53415*10^13, -6.68947*10^13, 1.20892*10^14, -2.08562*10^14, 
 3.43421*10^14, -5.39605*10^14, 8.08845*10^14, -1.15627*10^15, 
 1.57581*10^15, -2.04655*10^15, 2.53174*10^15, -2.98174*10^15, 
 3.34142*10^15, -3.56063*10^15, 3.60542*10^15, -3.46646*10^15, 
 3.1619*10^15, -2.73363*10^15, 2.23776*10^15, -1.73254*10^15, 
 1.26708*10^15, -8.74157*10^14, 5.68038*10^14, -3.47091*10^14, 
 1.9906*10^14, -1.06931*10^14, 5.36788*10^13, -2.5117*10^13, 
 1.09229*10^13, -4.40038*10^12, 1.63609*10^12, -5.5903*10^11, 
 1.74674*10^11, -4.96231*10^10, 1.27307*10^10, -2.92548*10^9, 
  5.96249*10^8, -1.06468*10^8, 
 1.63982*10^7, -2.13439*10^6, 228286., -19264.2, 1202.6, -49.3738, 1}
```

Looks reasonable. Next,

```
cfromr[foo]
{5.9802 + 0.0792079 I, -8.1594 + 0.0953864 I, 
10.3109 + 0.107405 I, -11.2502 - 0.144703 I, 
11.7326 + 0.0258995 I, -10.0821 + 0.0336182 I, 
8.24025 + 0.123999 I, -5.02346 + 0.598038 I, 0.450765 + 0.232466 I, 
4.02386 - 0.0386024 I, -10.1325 - 0.354894 I, 
15.4001 + 0.0682209 I, -20.8642 + 0.00860923 I, 
25.4178 + 0.0414025 I, -29.7352 - 0.0478316 I, 
32.0813 + 0.0872942 I, -34.4719 - 0.186356 I, 
34.9878 - 0.140137 I, -34.796 - 0.438696 I, 
34.1201 - 0.266264 I, -32.825 - 0.34352 I, 
31.1676 + 0.0377669 I, -28.6403 - 0.273897 I, 
26.9552 - 0.226578 I, -24.5299 - 0.210857 I, 
21.7318 - 0.166584 I, -18.3817 - 0.406169 I, 
14.7006 - 0.211768 I, -10.6488 + 0.0218902 I, 
5.89532 + 0.0502537 I, -2.43193 + 0.145602 I, -2.29822 + 0.0280126 I,
10.1683 + 0.0739904 I, -41.196 + 0.297882 I, 
204.612 + 0.22332 I, -1077.32 + 0.356418 I, 
5524.19 - 0.0830177 I, -27046.6 - 0.241576 I, 
125945. - 0.265022 I, -557670. + 0.314207 I, 
2.34902*10^6 + 0.110874 I, -9.41749*10^6 + 0.0519993 I, 
3.5953*10^7 - 0.0733092 I, -1.30763*10^8 - 0.0274269 I, 
4.53272*10^8 + 0.136665 I, -1.49802*10^9 + 0.139398 I, 
4.72179*10^9 - 0.00431823 I, -1.41987*10^10 - 0.0238292 I, 
4.07431*10^10 - 0.0859524 I, -1.11587*10^11 + 0.413876 I, 
2.91749*10^11 - 0.124791 I, -7.28283*10^11 + 0.0234331 I, 
1.73593*10^12 - 0.0233547 I, -3.9513*10^12 + 0.137854 I, 
8.58888*10^12 - 0.0113619 I, -1.78288*10^13 + 0.328116 I, 
3.53415*10^13 - 0.310418 I, -6.68947*10^13 + 0.0321282 I, 
1.20892*10^14 - 0.197183 I, -2.08562*10^14 + 0.314149 I, 
3.43421*10^14 - 0.127756 I, -5.39605*10^14 + 0.0133408 I, 
8.08845*10^14 + 0.0230662 I, -1.15627*10^15 - 0.272123 I, 
1.57581*10^15 - 0.192791 I, -2.04655*10^15 - 0.0992356 I, 
2.53174*10^15 + 0.342712 I, -2.98174*10^15 - 0.448979 I, 
3.34142*10^15 - 0.382704 I, -3.56063*10^15 - 0.161659 I, 
3.60542*10^15 - 0.245491 I, -3.46646*10^15 + 0.181787 I, 
3.1619*10^15 + 0.53769 I, -2.73363*10^15 + 0.379394 I, 
2.23776*10^15 + 0.0504824 I, -1.73254*10^15 + 0.3809 I, 
1.26708*10^15 + 0.062272 I, -8.74157*10^14 + 0.230549 I, 
5.68038*10^14 - 0.115016 I, -3.47091*10^14 + 0.317305 I, 
1.9906*10^14 - 0.0884983 I, -1.06931*10^14 - 0.00104238 I, 
5.36788*10^13 - 0.25693 I, -2.5117*10^13 + 0.218549 I, 
1.09229*10^13 + 0.26878 I, -4.40038*10^12 - 0.140603 I, 
1.63609*10^12 + 0.0812383 I, -5.5903*10^11 + 0.14043 I, 
1.74674*10^11 - 0.402052 I, -4.96231*10^10 + 0.272428 I, 
1.27307*10^10 - 0.0000964737 I, -2.92548*10^9 - 0.0669364 I, 
5.96249*10^8 - 0.168353 I, -1.06468*10^8 + 0.42484 I, 
1.63982*10^7 - 0.511921 I, -2.13439*10^6 - 0.268171 I, 
228291. - 0.242538 I, -19266.8 + 0.125755 I, 
1203.94 + 0.0223555 I, -48.8476 + 0.0424496 I, -1.905 - 0.0992187 I}
```

Notice that this is complete nonsense. The numbers are not real, and their magnitude is completely off. Either I am insane, or *Mathematica* is. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why the need to `Expand` in your first approach?

Comment: Closely related [Finding the coefficient of a certain power in a generating function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58850/finding-the-coefficient-of-a-certain-power-in-a-generating-function)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork How else would you find the coefficients?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Ah, I see, the `Expand[]` is implicit, but the system clearly does it, because removing the `Expand[]` does not speed things up.

Comment: @Artes Related, but not that closely. Computing a single coefficient is quite different from computing all of them (the tradeoffs are quite different).

Comment: Unless your complex numbers have a special property, I would expect the coefficients to quickly become non-machine numbers. If they were all machine numbers, than you could probaby quickly compute the power polynomials $\underset{i}{\overset{5000}{\sum }}r_i^k$ and then use the Newon-Girard identities to compute the symmetric polynomials, which up to a sign would be the coefficients of your polynomial.

Comment: I think your `InverseFourier` approach needs more than `MachinePrecision` to produce a correct result. If you replace the `Compile` with a normal function definition, and then arbitrarily set the precision of the input to 100, you will see that your function produces the same results.

Comment: @CarlWoll Yes, I guessed that, but it is puzzling, because the input seems to be not quite large enough to produce over/underflows. In fact, I would have thought that the FFT method would be MORE stable than the primitive method.

Comment: @CarlWoll In fact, notice that the primitive method does use machine precision also. By the way the other two methods (characteristic polynomial of a matrix and interpolating polynomial) both seem to produce junk as well.

Answer (score 6):

Multiplying two polynomials is equivalent to using [`ListConvolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListConvolve) on the coefficients of the polynomial. The only issue is that using [`ListConvolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListConvolve) will experience a catastrophic loss of precision. This can be mitigated by arbitrarily increasing the precision before using [`ListConvolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListConvolve). Here is a sample set of roots:

```
roots = RandomComplex[1+I, 5000];
```

Here is essentially the obvious method from your OP:

```
res1 = CoefficientList[Times @@ (roots-x), x]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {52.9876, Null}

Now, for the [`ListConvolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListConvolve) method. The first step is to use the obvious method in chunks of 100, since it is pretty fast for this size root list:

```
coeffList = Table[
    CoefficientList[Times @@ (k-x), x],
    {k, Partition[roots, 100]}
]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.477353, Null}

Now, we use [`ListConvolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListConvolve) on the coefficient lists, but arbitrarily raising the precision first:

```
res2 = Fold[
    ListConvolve[SetPrecision[#2,100], SetPrecision[#1,100], {1,-1}, 0]&,
    coeffList
]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {27.2074, Null}

Finally, the [`CharacteristicPolynomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CharacteristicPolynomial) method:

```
res3 = CoefficientList[
    CharacteristicPolynomial[DiagonalMatrix[roots], x],
    x
]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {42.9382, Null}

Now, let's compare the outputs:

```
res1[[-10;;]]
res2[[-10;;]]//N
res3[[-10;;]]
```

> {-1.59795*10^26 - 1.65294*10^26 I, 
>    5.87868*10^23 + 8.83793*10^21 I, -9.57174*10^20 + 9.32321*10^20 I, 
>    2.99454*10^16 - 2.65645*10^18 I, 
>    3.17046*10^15 + 3.23058*10^15 I, -6.42539*10^12 - 4.82769*10^10 I, 
>    5.18789*10^9 - 5.12975*10^9 I, -23330.2 + 6.21159*10^6 I, -2487.88 - 
>     2497.24 I, 1}
>
> {-1.59795*10^26 - 1.65294*10^26 I, 
>    5.87868*10^23 + 8.83793*10^21 I, -9.57174*10^20 + 9.32321*10^20 I, 
>    2.99454*10^16 - 2.65645*10^18 I, 
>    3.17046*10^15 + 3.23058*10^15 I, -6.42539*10^12 - 4.82769*10^10 I, 
>    5.18789*10^9 - 5.12975*10^9 I, -23330.2 + 6.21159*10^6 I, -2487.88 - 
>     2497.24 I, 1.}
>
> {-1.59795*10^26 - 1.65294*10^26 I, 
>    5.87868*10^23 + 8.83793*10^21 I, -9.57174*10^20 + 9.32321*10^20 I, 
>    2.99454*10^16 - 2.65645*10^18 I, 
>    3.17046*10^15 + 3.23058*10^15 I, -6.42539*10^12 - 4.82769*10^10 I, 
>    5.18789*10^9 - 5.12975*10^9 I, -23330.2 + 6.21159*10^6 I, -2487.88 - 
>     2497.24 I, 1}

The last 10 coefficients are in reasonable agreement, and the first 10 are as well. However, the middle coefficients are not in agreement. For instance:

```
res1[[3000]]
res2[[3000]]//N
res3[[3000]]
```

> -3.911349964088013*10^1154 + 6.655806866305701*10^1154 I
>
> -7.24028240645896*10^1153 + 1.217768123179758*10^1154 I
>
> -7.240282406458935*10^1153 + 1.217768123179755*10^1154 I

I'm inclined to believe the [`ListConvolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListConvolve) approach, because I can arbitrarily use even higher precision, and the output doesn't change:

```
res4 = Fold[
    ListConvolve[SetPrecision[#2,500], SetPrecision[#1,500], {1,-1}, 0]&,
    coeffList
]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {31.0709, Null}

```
res4[[3000]]//N
```

> -7.24028240645896*10^1153 + 1.217768123179758*10^1154 I

Finally, it is possible to tweak the [`ListConvolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListConvolve) approach by using different chunks. For example, here I use chunks of 500:

```
coeffList2 = Table[
    CoefficientList[Times @@ (k-x), x],
    {k, Partition[roots, 500]}
]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.46872, Null}

```
res5 = Fold[
    ListConvolve[SetPrecision[#2,1500], SetPrecision[#1,1500], {1,-1}, 0]&,
    coeffList2
]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {10.4263, Null}

Notice that this combination is more than twice as fast as using chunks of 100, but it requires insanely high precision to get outputs that agree with the 100 chunk approach:

```
res5[[3000]]//N
```

> -7.24028240645890*10^1153 + 1.217768123179749*10^1154 I

```
res5[[-10;;]]//N
```

> {-1.59795*10^26 - 1.65294*10^26 I, 
>    5.87868*10^23 + 8.83793*10^21 I, -9.57174*10^20 + 9.32321*10^20 I, 
>    2.99454*10^16 - 2.65645*10^18 I, 
>    3.17046*10^15 + 3.23058*10^15 I, -6.42539*10^12 - 4.82769*10^10 I, 
>    5.18789*10^9 - 5.12975*10^9 I, -23330.2 + 6.21159*10^6 I, -2487.88 - 
>     2497.24 I, 1. + 0. I}

For example, a precision of 1000 is not enough:

```
res5 = Fold[
    ListConvolve[SetPrecision[#2,1000], SetPrecision[#1,1000], {1,-1}, 0]&,
    coeffList2
]; //AbsoluteTiming

res5[[-10;;]]//N
```

> {7.1049, Null}
>
> {0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 
>    0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I}

Answer (score 1):

The coefficients of each term are sums of products of subsets of the roots with alternating sign.  e.g  (for an even number of roots)

```
coeffs = Subsets[roots, {#}] & /@ Range[Length[roots]];

plusminus = ConstantArray[{-1, 1}, Quotient[Length[coeffs], 2]] // Flatten

coefficientlist= (Total[Times @@@ #] & /@ coefs)*plusminus
```

Comment: Yes, but this makes the computation EXPONENTIAL time.

Answer (score 1):

Some (slight) savings are made by replacing `Product` by `Times` in your code

I would expect that `Series` would be most efficient for such a computation (it is more efficient than `CharacteristicPolynomial` and *should* be optimal), e.g.,

```
With[{p = Length[foo] + 1}, 
   PadLeft[(Times @@ (x - foo) + O[x]^p)[[3]], p]]
```

The `PadLeft` is required for zero roots.

[Wilkinson's polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson%27s_polynomial) illustrates that the location of the roots can be very sensitive to perturbations in the coefficients of the polynomial.

Comment: Actually, the `CharacteristicPolynomial` method is faster for large root lists.

Comment: Actually, computing the `Series` first and then applying `CharacteristicPolynomial` seems to be faster by almost a factor of 3 (at least for random integer coefficients) than just using `CharacteristicPolynomial`. However, for random reals, the times are comparable (tested with `p=2000`).